# PHP: Dynamic or Programmatic Catch Blocks

Tags: php, exception, dynamic, try-catch

I have a situation where it would be nice to be able to have a catch block where the type of the Exception is determined at run time. It would work something like this:

```
$someClassName = determineExceptionClass();

try {
  $attempt->something();
} catch ($someClassName $e) {
  echo 'Dynamic Exception';
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Default Exception';
}
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: I'm working on a library of sorts and I want the user to provide the class that is used for the exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That doesn't work as far as I'm aware. You could mimic that functionality with a control statement like this:

```
$someClass = 'SomeException';

try
{
    $some->thing();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    switch (get_class($e))
    {
        case $someClass:
            echo 'Dynamic exception.';
            break;
        default:
            echo 'Normal exception.';
    }
}
```

Comment: Not as elegant as my first idea but it works just the same. Thanks!